# Split string isn't matching to another string

Tags: java, string

When I've split a string into a string array, then trying to match it too a String.
Like this:

```
String[] thisString = "hello my name is".split(" ");
if (thisString[1] == "my"){
    System.out.print("My!");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Object comparison in Java should use `.equals()`.

use `.equals()` instead of  `==`

Example:

```
thisString[1].equals( "my")
```

`==` comparison checks for reference equality. `equals()` comparison checks for content equality.

Answer (score 2):

Please use [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)  rather than `==`.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you should use `String.equals` to check string content:

```
if (thisString[1].equals("my")) {
```

`String.split` will create a different object reference for the `String` "my" so the `ìf` statement expression will be false using the `==` operator.

Comment: Note that sometimes `==` will work for String comparison. This is because `==` checks object identity (same reference) and the JVM interns String and re-uses them when possible.

Answer (score 1):

**== compares, if both references the same object,** 
where as 
**.equals(string) compares if both string have same value or not**

So, Use `if (thisString[1].equals("my"))`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot actually compare strings using `==`. You need to use `equals()` method, which goes as:

`string1.equals(string2)`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing object and in `java` for object comparison we have `.equals()`

so in your case

```
if (thisString[1].equals("my"))
{
 System.out.print("My!");
}
```